# Are there any detrimental effects to long term electrical muscle stimulation?

Tags: muscles, electrical-stimulation

I know that different types of electrical stimulation can be used in fields such as physical therapy to get muscles to contract. However, these electrical stimulation sessions are not prolonged and contiguous.

Does anybody know if stimulating muscles to contract and retract for an extended and continuous period of time has negative side effects? Does it damage the muscle? Nerve?